# Excel always opens blank worksheet when opening a file

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I open an existing excel file (Version 2008 Build 13127.20638 of Office 365) excel always opens a blank worksheet in addition. Is this a known issue? Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

Go to this location: **C:\Users<User Name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel**

Clear all files from this folder.

Comment: Did not worked. Cleaned the whole folder, opened an existing file and still an empty worksheet is opened in addition.